# Download ans save many PDFs files with python

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to download many PDFS fle from a website and save them.

```
import requests
url = "https://jawdah.qcc.abudhabi.ae/en/Registration/QCCServices/Services/Registration/Trade%20Licenses/"+id+".pdf"
r = requests.get(url, stream= TRUE)
for id in range(1,125):
   with open(id+'.pdf',"wb") as pdf:
      for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
          if chunk:
              pdf.write(chunk)
```

THE first url of the pdf is https://jawdah.qcc.abudhabi.ae/en/Registration/QCCServices/Services/Registration/Trade%20Licenses/1.pdf

and the last url is https://jawdah.qcc.abudhabi.ae/en/Registration/QCCServices/Services/Registration/Trade%20Licenses/125.pdf

I want to download all this files.
When i execute this code i have this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\king-\OneDrive\Bureau\pdfs\pdfs.py", line 6, in <module>
    url = "https://jawdah.qcc.abudhabi.ae/en/Registration/QCCServices/Services/Registration/Trade%20Licenses/"+id+".pdf"
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "builtin_function_or_method") to str
```

Comment: In the second line you add a `str` to a built-in function (`id`). Don't use `id` as variable name.

Comment: Sorry i did not understand if you can write your solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second line

```
url = "https://jawdah.qcc.abudhabi.ae/en/Registration/QCCServices/Services/Registration/Trade%20Licenses/"+id+".pdf"
```

you add a `str` object to something named `id`. `id` is a built-in function (type `id()` in a python console). In line 4

```
for id in range(1,125):
```

you overwrite `id` with something else (a number), which is possible, but not recommendable.

Apart from that you just make a single request, not one for very file. Try this:

```
import requests
url = "https://jawdah.qcc.abudhabi.ae/en/Registration/QCCServices/Services/Registration/Trade%20Licenses/{}.pdf"
for num in range(1,126):
   r = requests.get(url.format(num), stream= TRUE)
   with open('{}.pdf'.format(num),"wb") as pdf:
      for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
          if chunk:
              pdf.write(chunk)
```

Comment: The underlying issue is not the overwriting of `id` (which is bad in its own way), but the "adding" of a string and an integer, which is not allowed.